# How to check if pointer is pointing to a valid memory address in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory

Sometimes I get a crash on my program with error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

and when I try to debug:

```
*(char*)&element->name
```

I get this error:

`Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory`

So my question is, is there a way to safely check this case and break from the function and avoid the crash?

I tried to do the next two checks:

```
if (!element->name) {
    return nil;
}
```

and

```
if (!(*(char*)&element->name)) {
    return nil;
}
```

but still get crash on `if` line.
I was googling around for few days already but cannot find a safe-check solution for this. Maybe you could help me with this. Is there a way to safely check if I can read from memory and if not to break from the function and avoid the crash?

Thanks in advance!
Please let me know if you need more information from me

Comment: Short of known-values (e.g. NULL), you can't. You can "tell" by not writing code resulting in indeterminate pointer values in the first place.

Comment: You could check if pointer address doesn't fall into `__PAGEZERO` assuming that's compiled for Apple targets.  That would give some elementary checks for low numbers which shouldn't be used as pointers in the first place (thing of checking for `nil` on steroids). But that's still far away from telling if a pointer is guaranteed to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no (standard, portable) way to tell if a pointer is valid based on the pointer value alone.

In fact, the only meaningful (standard, portable) test you can make is to check against `NULL`, which represents a well-defined *invalid* pointer value guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Which doesn’t help if you don’t properly initialize your pointer variables, or set them to `NULL` when not in use<sup>1</sup>.

There may be system-specific extensions that can tell you if a pointer is valid, bur I don’t personally know of any.

---

<sup>1.  Of course, the better option is for your pointer variables’ lifetime to be limited so that you *can’t* access an invalid pointer, but that’s not always easy to do.</sup>